# Sending Multiple Arguments to AJAX Success Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently having trouble with sending multiple arguments to a callback success function related to AJAX.

All I am pretty much looking to do is preserve the value of a variable that came in as a parameter to the function that the AJAX call is enclosed in.

I can get as far as the value being present in the native success function, but once I try to pass it and retrieve it in my call back method, all of a sudden the variable is undefined. I am confused as to why this is happening and thought the value would send to the function without an issue.

If anyone could shed some light on this I would greatly appreciate it. My thinking says this it probably has something to do with scope, $this, and how I'm passing my variable, but I haven't been able to put it all together yet. Below is my code:

```
function getNum(numb, parentWindow)
{

alert(parentWindow);

alert("before ajax");
$.support.cors = true;

            $.ajax
            ({
               type: "POST",
               crossDomain: true,
               beforeSend: function(request)
               {
                   request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic");
                   return true;
               },
           data: {
              'parentWindow' :parentWindow
           },
               url: webServiceURL,
               dataType: "xml",
           context: parentWindow,
               async: false,
               data: soapMessage, 
               contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
               success: function(data)
               {
                   alert(this);
                   alert(parentWindow);
                   OnSuccess(data, parentWindow);
               },          
               error: OnError
});     
}
```

The alerting of parentWindow right above, does come back as being an object. The second part is below for the OnSuccess function that is being called.

```
function OnSuccess(data, status, parentWindow)
    {

       alert("my window " + data.parentWindow);
       alert("my window " + this.parentWindow);

       var documentValArr = parseXMLRrec(data);

        if(documentValArr)
        {

        insertDataIntoTable(documentValArr);

        }

    }
```

The alerts in the OnSuccess function both return the parentWindow parameter as undefined and I'm just having a confusing time trying to figure out why this is. If anyone could give me a pointer or two I would be very thankful!

Comment: Your call to OnSuccess gets two parameters, but your function needs three parameters, so the third is undefined. `status` does not come out of nowhere. ;-) Happy Christmas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function OnSuccess(data, status, parentWindow)
```

this function takes 3 parameters.

```
OnSuccess(data, parentWindow);
```

You only send 2 parameters in. As it is now, your function receives `parentWindow` as `status`.

Assuming that the Ajax `success` callback has the data that you want (as you say: it has), then it is not a closure problem.

Comment: Ahhhh jeeze, I realized this was a small mistake. I think I've been looking at my code for too long, thank you, its working.

Answer (score 1):

Check your arguments and parameters order

```
success: function(data) { alert(this); alert(parentWindow); OnSuccess(data, parentWindow); },
```

Should be

```
success: function(data) { alert(this); alert(parentWindow); OnSuccess(data,'', parentWindow); },
```

In onSuccess function access the parentWindow without 'this' or 'data'

```
alert("my window " + parentWindow);
```